# How to force a JSP to send the page in ISO-8859-1?

Tags: jsp, encoding

I wanted to send a page in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) instead of [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). The page is built with a [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) and some content retrieved by a [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system).

I tried to put this in the JSP, but the navigator stills performs the page in UTF-8.

grid.jsp:

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" 
      pageEncoding="iso-8859-1"%>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
        </head>
```

What could be the problem?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you check what kind of content type header gets sent using Web Developer Toolbar or Firebug in Firefox?

Comment: And how did you test it and how did you conclude that it's still UTF-8? In Firefox you can check the encoding used by *View* > *Character Encoding*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is right:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" pageEncoding="iso-8859-1"%>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
        </head>
    <html>
```

With this code you can ensure the page is in iso-8859-1 unless there is a filter that changes the response, it was my case.

Thanks!!

Comment: Only the `pageEncoding` was been enough. It will automatically (implicitly) also set the contenttype, charset and HTTP (meta) header.